# Install shield Activation issue- internet activation failed

Tags: installation, setup, installshield

While activating Installshield software with key provided with download, it gives **Internet activation failed error**

[image: Error - 0 Failed to connect to the license server Check your Internet connection, and then try activation again.]

Comment: If this is a license you have paid for a current product, have you contacted support regarding this issue yet?